# Fill a datatable with a list in JSF 2.2

Tags: list, jsf, datatable

I'm trying to replicate this guide but with jsf 2.2:

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-datatable-example/

My current setup: a class called Message holds a date, string, and an account object called "name" (its owner). A MessageBean class has a List object messageSet, that gets initialized in the MessageBean constructor. A JSF page fills a table with the messageList. However, the table doesn't get filled. When looking at the list object in the debugger, it does get filled with valid message objects. My classes:
@Named(value = "messageBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MessageBean implements Serializable
{
    private List messageSet;

```
public MessageBean()
{
    this.messageSet = Controller.Controller.getLatestKweks();

}

public List<Message> getMessageSet()
{
    return messageSet;
}

public void setMessageSet(List<Message> messageSet)
{
    this.messageSet = messageSet;
}
}
```

The JSF page:

```
  <h:dataTable value="#{messageBean.messageSet}" var="mes">
            <h:column> 
                <f:facet name="header">Date</f:facet>
                    #{mes.mesDate}
            </h:column>
            <h:column> 
                <f:facet name="header">Naam</f:facet>
                    #{mes.name.accountName}
            </h:column>
            <h:column> 
                <f:facet name="header">Content</f:facet>
                    #{mes.Content}
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
```

There's a second Message object that is a Hibernate object, only having getters and setters in it.

Here's the stacktrace when I try to access this page:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "mesDate"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.toInteger(ArrayELResolver.java:378)
at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:198)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:227)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:150)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:302)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.renderRow(TableRenderer.java:385)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeChildren(TableRenderer.java:162)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

THe component tree:

```
 <UIViewRoot id="j_id1" inView="true" locale="en_GB" renderKitId="HTML_BASIC" rendered="true" transient="false" viewId="/hoofdpagina.xhtml">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<UIOutput id="j_idt2" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false">

    <title>Main page</title>

</UIOutput>

<UIOutput id="j_idt4" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false">

    <div id="menu">top</div> <div id="currentMessages">

    <HtmlDataTable border="-2147483648" first="0" id="j_idt6" inView="true" rendered="true" rowIndex="0" rowStatePreserved="false" rows="0" transient="false"   var="mes">

        <UIColumn header="Datum" id="j_idt7" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false">
            header

            Date

            #{mes.mesDate}

        </UIColumn>

        <UIColumn header="Name" id="j_idt10" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false">
            header

            Name

            #{mes.name.accountName}

        </UIColumn>

        <UIColumn header="Inhoud" id="j_idt13" inView="true" rendered="true"     transient="false">
            header

            Content

            #{mes.mesContent}

        </UIColumn>

    </HtmlDataTable>

    </div>

</UIOutput>

 </html>

 </UIViewRoot>
```

And the scoped variables:

```
  Name  Value
  j_idt6    j_idt6
 j_idt6:j_idt10 bread
 j_idt6:j_idt12 Log in
 j_idt6:j_idt8  Donald
 AttributesName Value
 None
 Request AttributesName Value
 kwek   [Ljava.lang.Object;@a5c775c
 Flash AttributesName   Value
 None
 Session AttributesName Value
 None
 Application AttributesName Value
 csfcff [ ]
```

Anyone have any idea why the table won't fill?

Comment: R u getting any error's

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I've added the exceptions I get when I try to access the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Hibernate/JPA query is broken. The code behind `getLatestKweks()` is *actually* returning a `List<Object[]>`, not `List<Message>`.

Evidence is in the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "mesDate"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.toInteger(ArrayELResolver.java:378)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:198)
    ...
```

The `ArrayELResolver` is **only** involved when the base of `mesDate` (thus, the `#{mes}`) represents an array like `Object[]` not a javabean like `Message`. EL is attempting to use the `mesDate` to obtain the array item by index, which can only be an integer like so `#{mes[0]}` for the 1st item. However, the string value `"mesDate"` is not parseable as an integer and hence this exception.

You have 2 options to solve this problem:

- Alter the code to expect a `List<Object[]>`. Use e.g. `#{mes[0]}`, `#{mes[1]}`, etc.
- Fix the Hibernate/JPA query to return a real `List<Message>`. Specify `Message.class` as type.

#### See also:

- [NumberFormatException for input String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412171/numberformatexception-for-input-string/)