# Showing Hibernate/JPA results in JSF datatable causes: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[propertyname]"

Tags: jsf, jpa, primefaces, datatable

I've initially the below query to obtain `List<Employee>`:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select table1 from Table as table1");
this.employees = (List<Employee>) query.list();
```

This is successfully rendered in below datatable:

```
<p:dataTable var="employee" value="#{bean.employees}">
    <p:column id="name" headerText="Name">
        <h:outputText value="#{employee.name}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column id="id" headerText="ID" >
        <h:outputText value="#{employee.id}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

However, when I try to retrieve it from 2 tables as below:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select a.name, b.id from Table1 as a, Table2 as b"); 
this.employees = (List<Employee>) query.list();
```

It throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "name"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown source)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.toInteger(ArrayELResolver.java:166)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:46)
    ...
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Hibernate query is *actually* returning a `List<Object[]>`, not a `List<Employee>` as you incorrectly assumed during the unchecked cast.

Evidence is in the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "name"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown source)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.toInteger(ArrayELResolver.java:166)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:46)
    ...
```

The `ArrayELResolver` is **only** involved when the base of `name` (thus, the `#{employee}`) represents an array like `Object[]` not a javabean like `Bean`. EL is attempting to use the `name` to obtain the array item by index, which can only be an integer like so `#{employee[0]}` for the 1st item. However, the string value `"name"` is not parseable as an integer and hence this exception.

You have 2 options to solve this problem:

- Alter the JSF code to expect a `List<Object[]>`. Use e.g. `#{employee[0]}`, `#{employee[1]}`, etc.

  ```
  <p:dataTable var="employee" value="#{bean.employees}">
      <p:column id="name" headerText="Name">
          <h:outputText value="#{employee[0]}" />
      </p:column>
      <p:column id="id" headerText="ID" >
          <h:outputText value="#{employee[1]}" />
      </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
  ```
- Fix the Hibernate query to return a *real* `List<Employee>`.

#### See also:

- [NumberFormatException for input String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412171/numberformatexception-for-input-string/)

Comment: Thanks for your response, i understand that i mentioned that column name while retrieving record from DB,that's why it retrieved as `Object[]` right.. My problem solved by your First option..i mentioned `#{emp[0]}` alone insteadOf mentioning the column name( `#{emp.empname}`)...Thank you very much ..

Answer (score 0):

To return "a real `List<Object>`" instead of a `List<Object[]>`, as @BalusC says, you must specify the class of the resulting instances.

```
getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM ...",
                 EntityUser.class
).getResultList();
```

Here it is: `EntityUser.class`.